# find the index that gives the second largest difference between two lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to identify the index between two equal length lists that gives the second maximum absolute value of the difference between each row.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
random.seed(2)
l1 = pd.DataFrame([random.randrange(100) for _ in range(10)])
l2 = pd.DataFrame([random.randrange(100) for _ in range(10)])

l1-l2

0
0   -20
1   -66
2   6
3   -28
4   -66
5   74
6   30
7   -42
8   -18
9   -15
```

Now, I can use `idxmax()` to get the index giving me the largest absolute value difference, which is row 5. My question is how can I get the index giving the second largest difference value?

```
(l1 - l2).abs().idxmax()
0    5
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: The easy way: sort, then slice (complexity `O(n log n)`)

```
(l1 - l2).abs().sort_values([0], ascending=False).index[1]
```

Option 2: `nlargest`, then `idxmin` (complexity `O(n)` ):

```
(l1 - l2).abs().nlargest(2, columns=[0]).idxmin()
```

**Note** your data actually have two rows with value `66` so you might get random answer between `1` and `4`.

Comment: `Option 1` How will this approach work if you are returning index after sorting the list

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar updated to return the index.

Comment: that still returns index from the sorted list, OP wants the index from the original list

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar no, it IS the index of the original dataframe.

Comment: @QuangHoang when there are repettive values, it is not properly working. For instance, ````nlargest(3,```` and ````nlargest(2,```` return the same index. Is there a way to get away with this issue?

Comment: `(l1-l2).abs().drop_duplicates()`...

Comment: I would like to get the correct indices rather than ignoring or dropping. In the example I shared, I should first get 5, then 1, and then 4. However, it gives me 5,1, and 1.

Comment: Then go for sort solution, and pass `kind='stable'` or `kind='mergesort'` to sort_values.

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the largest absolute difference with `idxmax()` then remove it from the list via its index and use `idxmax()` again, which then would give you the index of the second-largest absolute difference.

```
l = (l1 - l2)
largest_index = l.abs().idxmax()
del l[largest_index]
l.idxmax()
```

Since it is not quite clear if you want the index of the  second-largest absolute difference in the original `(l1 - l2)` this option will achieve this.

```
l = (l1 - l2)
largest_index = l.abs().idxmax()
l[largest_index] = 0
l.idxmax()
```

By setting the larges absolute difference to zero, a second call will give you the index of the second-largest absolute difference, but not change the size of `(l1 - l2)` nor alter its order.